# Get text between `<pre>` and `</pre>` into an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, arraylist

I need to get some specific text out of a string and get that into an arraylist, but I have no idea where to start.
The string looks like this:

```
String exampleString = "some text I don't know <pre>the text I want to get</pre><pre>Some more text I want to get</pre> some text I don't know"
```

But the problem is that I don't know how many text sections there are with `<pre> text </pre>` it's even possible that there aren't any of those sections at all.

So could anyone tell me how to get the texts between those `<pre>` and `</pre>` and how to get those into an arraylist.

Thank you so much!

UPDATE: What I do know about the text from which I said "some text I don't know" is that it doesn't contain `<pre>` or `</pre>`

Comment: have you tried a regex? something like `<pre>(.+?)</pre>`?

Comment: Do you want to get the whole string or split the string on the <pre>?

Comment: @paul No, could you please explain that a little further?

Comment: @Averroes as long as I get the text between `<pre>` and `</pre>` it's ok

Comment: I am not sure of what do you want but I wou want to get rid of the <pre> tags, you can try String myString = exampleString.replace("<pre>", "").replace("</pre>", "")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<pre>(.+?)</pre>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourText);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        //  matcher.group() will contain the match from the previous find() statement
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){}
```

edited: corrected regex syntax

Comment: But how do you do it when there are multiple sections which start with `<pre>` and end with `</pre>`?

Comment: that's what regex does. matcher.find() will return the next match. call it multiple times to find all matches.

Comment: And what do I have to fill in at yourText?

Comment: Oh I think I get it, is it `String exampleString = "some text I don't know <pre>the text I want to get</pre><pre>Some more text I want to get</pre> some text I don't know"`?

Comment: yes - yourText is the text that you want to search for `<pre>` tags

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's no embedded tags you can do something like this:

```
private List<String> getText(String text){

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] sections = text.split("<pre>");
    int i = 0;
    for (String s : sections) {
        i = s.indexOf("</pre>");
        if (i >= 0)          
           results.add(s.substring(0, i));        
    }  
    return result;
}
```

Example of code running when

say:

```
text = "test text here <pre> item one </pre> and then another item <pre> item 2 </pre> and then some stuff."
```

So the first thing to explain is:

```
String[] sections = text.split("<pre");
```

This defines a new array of strings and assigns it to the result of a call to the String split function of "text"

This function breaks the string up in to sections delimited by `"<pre>"` so you get:

```
sections[0] = "test text here" 
sections[1] = "item one </pre> and then another item"
sections[2] = "item 2 </pre> and then some stuff."
```

so as you can see from that all we now need to do is remove anything after `"</pre>"` which is where the next bit comes in:

```
for (String s : sections)
```

Is the start of a "for each" loop that assigns the String s to each element of the array sections in turn.

So for each of the 3 strings above we do this:

```
 i = s.indexOf("</pre>");
    if (i >= 0)          
       results.add(s.substring(0, i));
```

So if the string contains `</pre>` then take a substring from the begining up until the `"</pre>"` and add it to our results. Since sections[1] and sections[2] so contain it they will end up in the results.

I hope this helps?

---

Here's how i'd implement JavaJugglers solution to avoid using while (true):

```
private List<String> getText(String text){
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    int indexStart = text.indexOf("<pre>");
    int indexEnd = text.indexOf("</pre>");
    while (indexStart >= 0 && indexEnd > indexStart) {
        result.add(text.substring(indexStart + 5, indexEnd));
        text = text.substring(indexEnd + 6);
        indexStart = text.indexOf("<pre>");
        indexEnd = text.indexOf("</pre>");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It's Java for each syntax, using iterator objects. Introduced in Java 5 I think. It just means for each String in the array called sections, set s to reference that String and do this code. See:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for both of your solutions, but with the second solution, don't you get in an infinite loop because the indexStart and indexEnd don't change because the exampleString don't change or am I wrong?

Comment: No, you are correct, that code is wrong, it should be "text" not "exampleString" i'll edit.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much for your patience, the second answer does is exactly what I want. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You should use the first solution anyway, the algorithm is better since it only ever requires 2 parses through the entire string. and less chopping and changing of references.

Comment: Ok, I don't really get this piece of code: `String[] sections = text.split("<pre>");` and I don't know what string s contains. Could you explain please?

Comment: I'll add an explanation to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure the HTML will be well-formed, you can start by using simple [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) methods:

```
String foo = "some text I don't know <pre>the text I want to get</pre><pre>Some more text I want to get</pre> some text I don't know";
int preStart = foo.indexOf("<pre>");
int preEnd = foo.indexOf("</pre>", preStart);

if (preStart > -1 && preEnd > preStart)
{
    String inBetweenTags = foo.substring(preStart + 5, preEnd);
    System.out.println(inBetweenTags);
}
```

http://ideone.com/OkE9B

Otherwise use an HTML parser.

Comment: But what does this code do when there are multiple text sections with `<pre>` and `</pre>` ?

Comment: It gets the first such section.

Comment: Even if the XML is well formed but there are embedded <pre> elements this will go wrong, as you will end up with multiple open tags, but stop reading from the first close.

Comment: @GlenLamb well-formed HTML != well-formed XML. Valid HTML cannot nest `<pre>` tags. At any rate, the OP did say that _"What I do know about the text from which I said "some text I don't know" is that it doesn't contain `<pre>` or `</pre>`."_

Comment: Ok, and then you could use the replaceFirst("<pre>", "") method and replaceFirst("</pre>", "") and start the block over again. Nice thank you.

Comment: But i'm trying to understand this code. Why do you use `preEnd > preStart` in `if (preStart > -1 && preEnd > preStart)` and `+ 5` in `foo.substring(preStart + 5, preEnd)`

Comment: @Merlin to make sure that `</pre>` was actually found in the string, _after_ `<pre>`. It's a bit of a belt-and-suspenders check, since I'm already using `String#indexOf(String, int)`.

Comment: I get it and why do you use `+ 5` in `foo.substring(preStart + 5, preEnd)`?

Comment: @Merlin because 5 is the length of the string `"<pre>"`. `String#indexOf(String)` returns the index in the string where the substring _starts,_ so I need to add the length of the substring to skip past it.

Comment: Oh, I get it thank you. But what do you think is the best solution to get all of the text sections which start with `<pre>` and end with `</pre>`?

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a simple solution:

```
private List<String> getText(String text){

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(true){
        int indexStart = text.indexOf("<pre>");
        int indexEnd = text.indexOf("</pre>");
        if(indexStart >= 0 && indexEnd >= 0 && indexEnd > indexStart){
            result.add(text.substring(indexStart + 5, indexEnd));
            text = text.substring(indexEnd + 6);
        }
        else{
            break;
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

Please keep in mind that you could change this function to be more generic, like passing the String to search as a parameter and calculate the substring offsets dynamically. I don't recommend you to use regular expressions because you may have Strings like:

```
<pre>text<pre>more text</pre>some more text</pre>
```

with nested "pre" tags.

Comment: Why does while(true) shocks you so much?

Comment: Why do you use while(true) could you please explain?

Comment: You loop until your program calls break instruction to get out of the loop, in this case it's when there are no more opening and closing "pre" occurrences.

Comment: While (true) is bad practise as far as I'm concerned, and can be confusing. (case in point). At the very least you should use while (!done). Also your condition in the if doesn't need the second check, since if indexEnd > indexStart it will definitely be greater than 0.

Comment: But why do you have to use the `+ 5` and `+ 6` in `result.add(text.substring(indexStart + 5, indexEnd));
            text = text.substring(indexEnd + 6);`

Comment: @Glen Lamb while(true) is not a bad practice. It's actually very normal. You would be surprised if you knew how many "trusty" software or APIs you use nowadays does while(true) loops. It's very common in network communication applications.

Comment: Just because people do a thing, doesn't mean that thing is good. It's confusing and mostly a throwback to older lang ages where it's needed. Or just bad habit. In your case, you have a clear condition that you use to break so it's even worse. See my answer for how I'd code your solution. (I still think my solution is much neater though)

Comment: @Glen Lamb Why did you edited your post with my supposed "improved" version? You then realized that do/while executes first and evaluates later? ;-) Junior mistake and completely error prone to IndexOutOfBounds... not to mention the arrogance of improving my solution, failing miserably, and cleaning the mess editing the post

Comment: Merlin is clearly new to Java, I'm trying to be helpful like anyone else here. I edited my post to explain why I think that While(true) is not needed, and code can't be posted in comments that well. I've stated that it's your solution and i'm not trying to take credit for it.

Yes, do / while wasn't right in that situation, but I did notice almost instantly and changed it so why is that a problem. I was trying to help a new Java developer by not teaching them bad habits, While (true) can make code unreadable and can easily be avoided, so why not avoid it?